# Meteor database design to prevent performance degradation

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-performance

Let's say I have an app that allows users to create ingredients.

I want each user to have 200 ingredients already in the system ready for them to use and edit upon joining the app. Now because I want to allow them the posibility to edit their ingredients, I believe I need to add the 200 ingredients to the database with the createdBy field set to their user id upon account creation. This way a user will only see and edit their own set of ingredients and not someone elses.

My question is in regards to performance...

If I have 10 users join, the ingredients collection now has 1000 documents. If in 6 months time I have 5000 users. The ingredients collection now has 5 million documents (plus the ingredients users create on their own). 5000 users is great, but what if theres even more.

Correct me if I am wrong but I am pretty sure that this would degrade performance as time goes by wouldn't it? If the query is searching through millions of documents, a user would most likely be waiting quite some time before their ingredients are displayed on the page right?

Is there any other way I can achieve what I want without this potential problem?

Thanks

Comment: Some ideas: (1) add the ingredients only when the user actually uses them, (2) store all of a user's ingredients in a single document, (3) Store a reference count in each ingredient document instead of repeating it (e.g. if 500 people have milk, only have one milk doc with 500 userIds). I'd recommend asking this on meteor forums instead, as it's way too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWeldon for your ideas. I didn't think of any of those so they are certainly filling in some gaps. I will do as you suggest about asking Meteor forums aswell. Thanks!